# Are humans more attracted to numbers or words, and what can that tells us about how we communicate?

Tags: reference-request, communication, language-processing, hyperscanning

I'm wondering if there's any peer-reviewed evidence which suggests whether humans scan numbers or words first when both are presented at the same time. For instance, if we had a sheet of paper where in one corner it had written "370" and on an opposite corner it had written "Cow", once we would turn this side of the paper towards the group study and ask them which one they read first, do we know if the majority of the people would scan the word or the number first? In this example I would obviously be writing the numbers and words in rotating corners so the position on the paper wouldn't have an influence on the answer.

In case this study has been conducted, and if there's an overwhelming amount of people that scan the number first than the word, could this tell us anything about how we communicate? Would we be able to express ourselves and understand others in a more efficient way if we were, somehow, using numbers instead of letters when writing?